# Print Above line and below four lines if a pattern matchs

Tags: awk, sed, solaris

I have a text file say input.txt which contains below data

```
$ cat input.txt

text1
error
text2
text3
text4
xyz
asd
asdf
text10
error
text11
text12
text13
text14
def
ghi
jkl
text16
error
text17
text18
text19
text20
```

I'm searching for 'error' in input file.
So I need to print the previous one line and next 4 lines when pattern matches.
Also, the patter can occur in multiple times.

I need output as below

```
text1
error
text2
text3
text4
text10
error
text11
text12
text13
text14
text16
error
text17
text18
text19
text20
```

Operating system is Solaris, So `grep -A` doesn't work here

Comment: Don't you have GNU `grep` at `/usr/gnu/bin/grep`?

Comment: nope, only have usr/bin/grep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/error/ {n = 6}
           n {print prev; n--}
             {prev = $0}
         END {if (n) print}
    ' < your-file
```

Or to add an empty line between those groups of 6 (assuming no overlapping) lines:

```
awk '/error/ {n = 6; if (x++) print ""}
           n {print prev; n--}
             {prev = $0}
         END {if (n) print}
    ' < your-file
```

Make sure to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, `nawk` or `/usr/gnu/bin/awk` on Solaris. The one in `/bin` is ancient from the 70s and doesn't support the modern standard syntax.

If you have `/usr/gnu/bin/awk` though (`text/gawk` package), chances are you have `/usr/gnu/bin/grep` as well (`text/gnu-grep` package) and could then use its `-A`/`-B` extensions:

```
/usr/gnu/bin/grep -B1 -A4 error < your-file
```

(GNU `grep` separates non-overlapping groups with `--` lines).

Comment: it works like charm :D, can you also help me in adding an extra new line "\n" after each iteration, like after each match and prints all the 6 lines extra new line needs to be added

Comment: Excellently elegant!